Dialogflow CX does not maches DTMF sent by API
My Dialogflow agent has DTMF. I have to use my agent via api. Everything works fine, except DTMF matching. I see in the response that the DTMF is recognized, but it is not matched with any transition.
"match": {
  "intent": null,
  "parameters": null,
  "resolvedInput": "",
  "matchType": "NO_MATCH",
  "confidence": 1,
  "event": "sys.no-match-1"
},
"dtmf": {
  "digits": "1",
  "finishDigit": ""
},


If I test it in Dialogflow, then everything works fine, DTMF is recignized, and matched.
  "match": {
    "confidence": 1,
    "intent": {
      "displayName": "DTMF_1",
      "name": "projects/xxx/locations/europe-west2/agents/xxx/intents/xxx"
    },
    "matchType": "DIRECT_INTENT"
  },
  "dtmf": {
    "digits": "1",
    "transformed": true
  },


If I uncheck the Send new DTMF input while testing from dialogflow, then it looks similar as in first case, the DTMF is recognized, but not matched:
  "match": {
    "confidence": 1,
    "event": "sys.no-match-1",
    "matchType": "NO_MATCH"
  },
  "dtmf": {
    "digits": "1"
  },

Question is, how can I make DTMF work from API?

Can you take a look at this link?

Matching works if I test it in dialogflow.
It looks to me that I had to do someting differently from the API. But API is very limited regarding DTMF.
